# Show validation messages in laravel

Tags: laravel

I wrote this code for storing products :

```
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'trans_data.*.name' => 'required', //translation data
            'trans_data.*.description' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required',
            'action' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

'*' is for lots of languages and we have 5 languages , I wrote this code for error message but I think it needs refactor.

```
 public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'trans_data.en.name.required' => 'English name is required',
            'trans_data.nl.name.required' => 'Dutch name is required',
            'trans_data.en.description.required' => 'English description is required',
            'trans_data.nl.description.required' => 'Dutch description is required'
            .
            .
            .
        ];
    }
```

I want to summarize these lines, and languages be dynamic like :

```
:attribute name is required
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You would have to write a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) to achieve that.

Comment: If you can please say how make a rule for this one @Repox

Comment: That's not how SO works. I linked you the documentation, make an attempt to solve your problem and ask a specific issue you need help with.